# What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix function gmtime_r?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unix, time, porting

I am porting some Unix code into Windows Visual Studio 2010. I have run into the following line

```
gmtime_r(&now, &tm_time);
```

I found that gmtime_r() is a standard Unix function, but I am hoping to find the Windows equivalent. I found quite a few gmtime functions in time.h, but I am having trouble finding which one is equivalent, if it even exists. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

gmtime_r() is the thread-safe version of gmtime().  The MSVC implementation of gmtime() is already thread safe, the returned struct tm* is allocated in thread-local storage.

That doesn't make it immune from trouble if the function is called multiple times on the same thread and the returned pointer is stored.  You can use gmtime_s() instead.  Closest to gmtime_r() but with the arguments reversed ;)