# difference between gmtime_r and gmtime_s

Tags: c++, time, thread-safety

Which is the difference between these two functions? I'm using MinGW 4.8.0.

I know that `gmtime_r` is thread safe ( but not secure if called multiple time from the same thread) but I don't understand `gmtime_s`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix function gmtime\_r?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044519/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-function-gmtime-r)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference is that [`gmtime_r(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime_r) is a [standard SUSv2 function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/gmtime.html). The closest you can find to `gmtime_r()` on a windows environment is [`gmtime_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3stkd9be.aspx), which has its arguments reversed:

- `gmtime_r(const time_t*, struct tm*)`
- `gmtime_s(struct tm*, const time_t*)`

Basically, they both convert a time value to a `tm` structure. `gmtime_r` then return a pointer to this structure (or `NULL` if failed), whereas `gmtime_s` returns `0` if successful, and a `errno_t` in case of failure.

The `tm` structure has the following body, as can be seen from both docs listed above:

```
struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

Comment: Regarding gmtime_s: as from what I can see, the Windows the standard localtime and gmtime functions are already thread-safe, so yes

Comment: as for regarding gmtime_r, [taken from here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime_r): "The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe. Thread-safe versions asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r() and localtime_r() are specified by SUSv2"

Comment: I know that on Windows that functions are thread safe ( they use thread local storage ) and I know that on posix they're not, so posix provide `*_r` alternative. Now I'm using MinGW 4.8.0 (posix, dw2) that provides both `*_r` and `*_s`. MinGW links to msvcrt.dll (on Windows Xp is at version 7.0.2600.5512 ). So I'm not sure

Comment: @Streppel: Just one note: I'm pretty sure SUS and POSIX are two different (if related) things.

Answer (score 11):

`gmtime_r` and `localtime_r` are standard POSIX functions.

Their main purpose is *thread safety* (reentrancy).  The basic `gmtime` and `localtime` functions aren't thread-safe or reentrant, because they use a single static area to store their results, so `gmtime_r` and `localtime_r` take pointers to where the results should be stored.

`gmtime_s` and `localtime_s` were introduced by Microsoft and are now part of C11, although [non-Microsoft support is limited](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations). (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372980/25507) for further discussion.)

Their main purpose is *security*.  They were added as part of Microsoft's [Secure CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) (Secure C Run-Time).  From what I understand, thread safety isn't an issue with `gmtime` and `localtime` in Microsoft's CRT, since these functions' static output areas are already allocated per thread.  Instead, `gmtime_s` and `localtime_s` were added to do the Secure CRT's [parameter validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx). (In other words, they check if their parameters are NULL, in which case they invoke error handling.)

Comment: `gmtime_s` and `localtime_s` are in C11 too.

Comment: @FaTony - I had forgotten that. Thank you for the info; I updated my answer.

Comment: While documented as not thread-safe, `gmtime` and `localtime` are commonly implemented using thread-local storage and thus are effectively thread-safe. However, they are not reentrant.

Comment: Just looked at the glibc implementation and apparently I recalled incorrectly. The storage is not allocated thread-locally.