# gmtime_r((time_t*)&title->start_time, &start_time);

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to compile on Microsoft visual studio 2013 on C++ a program written for linux 
( is a mix of C and C++ (#include .h) and I'm going to convert all in C++  to not be more confused !)

the statement:

```
gmtime_r((time_t*)&title->start_time, &start_time);
```

return errors:  Error   11  error C3861: 'gmtime_r': identifier not found 
IntelliSense: identifier "gmtime_r" is undefined

please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between gmtime\_r and gmtime\_s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051762/difference-between-gmtime-r-and-gmtime-s)

Comment: You may find this SO thread useful: [What is the Windows equivalent of the Unix function gmtime_r?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12044519/1629821)