# how to check null pointer dereferencing when we have values instead of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, time, dereference

The syntax for the gmtime function in the C Language is:

```
struct tm *gmtime(const time_t *timer);
```

usual call to gmtime would be

```
tm *xx = gmtime( &curr_time );
```

which would make it easier  to check if NULL pointer was returned by gmtime function.

```
if (xx)
    return sucess;
```

### however it is not safe as The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

---

so one of the safer approach would be to use

```
time_t curr_time = time(0);
tm xx = *gmtime( &curr_time );
```

but in case the if the call is made like this

### how to check for null before dereferencing xx variable?

"not safe" source -- https://linux.die.net/man/3/gmtime

Comment: Are you in a multi-threaded setting where a subsequent call can come out of the blue?

Comment: You can use gmtime_r() instead

Comment: `struct tm *c; struct tm xx = (c = gmtime(&curr_time)) ? c : /* what should I put here? */;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from man-page

> The gmtime() function converts the calendar time timep to broken-down time representation, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It may return NULL when the year does not fit into an integer. The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions. **The gmtime_r() function does the same, but stores the data in a user-supplied struct**.

So, you just have to do

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm result;

if (!gmtime_r(&now, &result)) {
  // error
}
```

Then, "result" can't be over-written by another time function call.

Comment: thanks, but gmtime_r()  is undefined (why?? probably another question)

Comment: That because you don't have defined featured macro. From man page :Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r(), localtime_r():
    _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE

Comment: `gmtime_r()` is not standard C, although possible available to OP using other extended libraries.

Comment: Yes, but since he give a link to linux.die and not msdn, I assumed that is OS is Linux-like, and then give the thread safe function of gmtime for this case. For both windows / linux, there is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044519/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-function-gmtime-r)

Comment: yes, the target system is linux based embedded system.

Comment: There are far more choices than just `linux and msdn.  IAC, the post is not tagged Linux and so a Linux solution is a good guess but not a certainty.